# Get the final name of a video or picture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, rename

Hey guys , how can I get the final name of a picture or video that I record ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you take the picture with UIImagePickerController's `-takePicture` method, the picker's delegate gets a `-imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` message. The *info* parameter to that method is a dictionary that contains, among other things, the URL of the picture.